# In IIS, can I safely remove the X-Powered-By ASP.NET header?

Tags: asp.net, iis, header

Will this cause any harm? Does it serve any purpose other than tell browsers you have .net installed?

I like this article about changing the header to Pure Evil. Genius!

http://www.iishacks.com/index.php/2009/11/11/remove-x-powered-by-aspnet-http-response-header/

Comment: Maybe this belongs on Server Fault?

Comment: Maybe, but there isn't much activity over there! It COULD be programming related if it impacts anything downstream...

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This header (and a few other headers) is not required or used by modern browsers and can safely be removed from the web site configuration in IIS without consequence. Other server-side languages also tend to include a "Powered by..." header that can be safely removed. Here is another article that claims the same thing:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210506093425/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120209-1.aspx

> [...]
>
> The Server, X-Powered-By,
>   X-AspNet-Version, and
>   X-AspNetMvc-Version HTTP headers
>   provide no direct benefit and
>   unnecessarily chew up a small amount
>   of bandwidth. Fortunately, these
>   response headers can be removed with
>   some configuration changes.

Answer (score 41):

Add this to your web.config section

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: But this configuration will only affect the particular site, not all deployed application, am I right?

Comment: How could this answer have this many votes? This doesn't answer to the question at all. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier And yet this is exactly the answer that I, and presumably lots of other people needed. It gets my vote.

Comment: @boleslaw.smialy you can change this setting on all configuration levels. Site `web.config` but also `applicationhost.config` (for all of them if inherited and not overwritten). In fact the applicationhost config is the one that adds it in the first place, which you can remove.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can remove it,it will not affect anything. All x-headers are custom/non standard and informational only by definition. Browsers ignore them. The only thing it could affect is some kind of custom application that actually uses them for something e.g. a web crawler that gathers statistics on what technology is being used on what website might use the header to determine if a site uses asp.net. They don't actually do anything.

Comment: Anything to support this, or is this from personal experience?

Comment: This is not a general rule that should be followed. X-Frame Options is an "x-header" that would have very real consequences for removing without understanding what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can remove it and it will give away less information to automated hacking tools and here you have a tutorial how to get a rid of Server, X-AspNet-Version, X-AspNetMvc-Version (if you use ASP.NET MVC) and X-Powered-By

http://arturito.net/2011/10/21/how-to-remove-server-x-aspnet-version-x-aspnetmvc-version-and-x-powered-by-from-the-response-header-in-iis7/